# Get extension in Uploader

Tags: ruby, carrierwave

How do you get the file extension in a CarrierWave Uploader? I have quite honestly tried everything I can think of. I introspected the crap out of it.

This doesn't work:

```
def filename
  'filename' + self.extension
end
```

I'm trying to make custom file names and It's not working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had a very similar requirement and I solved it this way:

```
  def filename
    if original_filename
      @name ||= Digest::MD5.hexdigest(File.dirname(current_path))
      "#{@name}.#{file.extension}"
    end
  end
```

It works fine.